# LaTeX - Simple Text over Image

Tags: latex

I'm replicating an word documment and need to place some text over an image in the header, but i can't find a simple method to do that.

It's just some text centered over a retangular image, but the best anwser I've found, so far, for doing that is reading an 880 page manual for PFG package.
Is there anyway to do that with some simple package, like minipage?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Dall If your pgf manual only has 880 pages, it must be way outdated. The current one has 1318 pages (and growing)

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach using tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node at (current bounding box.center) {Quack};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]